# Unpivot/Transpose in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

[image]

I have a dynamic table in the format shown in the image (left hand side). A new month column will be added every month.
How do I unpivot month in Presto?
I can do it with this code below but I'll have to write it every month when there is a new column.
Is there any better way?

```
Select 
    KPI, KPI_Owner,month,
    t2.Value
From Table T1
CROSS JOIN unnest (
    array['2021_jan','2021_feb','2021_mar'],
    array["2021_jan", "2021_feb", "2021_mar"]
) t2(month,value)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.